# Regex match word followed by decimal from text

Tags: c#, regex

I want to be able to match the following examples and return array of matches

given text:

```
some word
another 50.00 
some-more 10.10 text
another word
```

Matches should be (word, followed by space then decimal number (Optionally followed by another word):

```
another 50.00 
some-more 10.10 text
```

I have the following so far:

```
     string pat = @"\r\n[A-Za-z ]+\d+\.\d{1,2}([A-Za-z])?";
        Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match m = r.Match(input);
```

but it only matches first item: `another 50.00`

Comment: Will the decimal number always have a decimal point, and have exactly 2 numbers after the decimal, or how else could it vary? And if numbers do show up that don't meet that pattern, do you want to include them or exclude them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not account for `-` with `[A-Za-z ]` and only match some text after a newline.

You can use the following regex:

```
[\p{L}-]+\p{Zs}*\d*\.?\d{1,2}(?:\p{Zs}*[\p{L}-]+)?
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D-%5D%2B%5Cp%7BZs%7D*%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%7B1%20%2C2%7D(%3F%3A%5Cp%7BZs%7D*%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D-%5D%2B)%3F&i=some%20word%0D%0Aanother%2050.00%20%0D%0Asome-more%2010.10%20text%0D%0Aanother%20word)

The `[\p{L}-]+` matches 1 or more letters and hyphens, `\p{Zs}*` matches 0 or more horizontal whitespace symbols, `\d*\.?\d{1,2}` matches a float number with 1 to 2 digits in the decimal part, and `(?:\p{Zs}*[\p{L}-]+)?` matches an optional word after the number.

Here is a C# snippet matching all occurrences based on [`Regex.Matches` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"[\p{L}-]+\p{Zs}*\d*\.?\d{1,2}(?:\p{Zs}*[\p{L}-]+)?")
              .Cast<Match>()
              .Select(p => p.Value)
              .ToList();
```

Just FYI: if you need to match whole words, you can also use word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b[\p{L}-]+\p{Zs}*\d*\.?\d{1,2}(?:\p{Zs}*[\p{L}-]+)?\b
```

And just another note: if you need to match diacritics, too, you may add `\p{M}` to the character class containing `\p{L}`:

```
[\p{L}\p{M}-]+\p{Zs}*\d*\.?\d{1,2}(?:\p{Zs}*[\p{L}\p{M}-]+)?\b
```

Comment: If you have any doubts, please feel free to drop a comment. Note that if you need to only allow ASCII letters, use your `[a-zA-Z]` character class instead of `\p{L}`.

Comment: I only get one match, the first one still. I was hoping to get an array of strings

Comment: that works. perfect. Thank you. will accept in 5 min

Comment: I think you might suggest `\p{L}\p{M}*+` instead of just `\p{L}` to allow Unicode diacritics that are separate code points not combined with the preceding letter. [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: I was typing that but my 1,5-year old daughter has deleted it - she's watching a cartoon   and having supper on my knees at the same time :)

Comment: @ErikE: No, but it supports atomic groups.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of them and .Net's support of them, and am happy to know I can use them as a replacement for possessive quantifiers (I said it wrong before.)